# Centering a pspicture vertically inside tabular

Tags: tables, pspicture

How can I center the pspicture vertically inside the cell? Using m-type-cell doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV=15,oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
\begin{tabular}{m{0.47\textwidth}m{0.47\textwidth}}
\toprule
\raisebox{0pt}[\dimexpr\height]{\begin{pspicture}
\psframe(0,0,)(6,5)
\end{pspicture}} & 
\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the argument for `\raisebox` to `2\pslinewidth`seems to give what you want:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV=15,oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array, cellspace}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
\begin{tabular}{m{0.47\textwidth}m{0.47\textwidth}}
\toprule
\raisebox{-2\pslinewidth}[\height]
{\begin{pspicture}(0,0,)(6,5)
\psset{dimen =inner}
\psframe(0,0,)(6,5)
\end{pspicture}
}
& Lalala
\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]