# Using m-column with PsPicture

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, pspicture

According to an older post ([see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356638/centering-a-pspicture-vertically-inside-tabular)) I'm trying to center a PsPicture inside a cell. The code I used before (`raisebox{0pt}[\height]{...}`) doesn't seem to work for this picture as the space above and below the picture are different:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV=15,oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
\begin{tabular}{m{6.5cm}m{3cm}}
\toprule
\raisebox{0pt}[\dimexpr\height]{\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](1,0)(7,1.2)
\psline*[linewidth=2pt,linecolor=black](3.7,0)(4.3,0)(4,0.32)
\psline[linewidth=1.5pt](2,0.8)(2,0.35)(6,0.35)(6,0.8)
\psframe[linecolor=blue,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue](1.1,0.85)(1.4,1.2)
\psframe[linecolor=blue,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue](1.5,0.85)(1.8,1.2)
\pscircle[linecolor=red,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red](2.05,1){0.15}
\pscircle[linecolor=red,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red](2.4,1){0.15}
\pscircle[linecolor=red,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red](2.75,1){0.15}
%
\pscircle[linecolor=red,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red](5.3,1){0.15}
\pscircle[linecolor=red,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red](5.65,1){0.15}
\pscircle[linecolor=red,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red](6,1){0.15}
\pscircle[linecolor=red,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red](6.35,1){0.15}
\pscircle[linecolor=red,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red](6.7,1){0.15}
%
\psline[linewidth=2.1pt](1,0.79)(3,0.79)
\psline[linewidth=2.1pt](5,0.79)(7,0.79)
\end{pspicture}} &
$\displaystyle 2x + 3 = 5$
\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
     \documentclass[a4paper,DIV=15,oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
     \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
     \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
     \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
     \usepackage{booktabs}
     \usepackage{graphicx}
     \usepackage{array}
     \usepackage{setspace}
     \usepackage{pst-all}
     \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
     \newcommand{\CenterObject}[1]{\ensuremath{\vcenter{\hbox{#1}}}}

     \begin{document}
     \onehalfspacing
     \begin{tabular}{m{6.5cm}m{3cm}}
     \toprule
     \raisebox{0pt}[\dimexpr\height]{
     \CenterObject{\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](1,0)(7,1.2)
     \psline*[linewidth=2pt,linecolor=black](3.7,0)(4.3,0)(4,0.32)
     \psline[linewidth=1.5pt](2,0.8)(2,0.35)(6,0.35)(6,0.8)
     \psframe[linecolor=blue,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue](1.1,0.85)(1.4,1.2)
     \psframe[linecolor=blue,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue](1.5,0.85)(1.8,1.2)
     \pscircle[linecolor=red,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red](2.05,1){0.15}
     \pscircle[linecolor=red,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red](2.4,1){0.15}
     \pscircle[linecolor=red,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red](2.75,1){0.15}
     %
     \pscircle[linecolor=red,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red](5.3,1){0.15}
     \pscircle[linecolor=red,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red](5.65,1){0.15}
     \pscircle[linecolor=red,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red](6,1){0.15}
     \pscircle[linecolor=red,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red](6.35,1){0.15}
     \pscircle[linecolor=red,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red](6.7,1){0.15}
     %
     \psline[linewidth=2.1pt](1,0.79)(3,0.79)
     \psline[linewidth=2.1pt](5,0.79)(7,0.79)
     \end{pspicture}}} &
     $\displaystyle 2x + 3 = 5$
     \\\bottomrule
     \end{tabular}
     \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but why isn't the combination of `\raisebox` and m-column capable of centering the picture? What's different (internally) when using math mode and `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}`?

Comment: It also seems like `raisebox` is no longer needed in your MWE ...

Comment: @Gotti I agree that `\raisebox` is not needed and unfortunately I do not know the deeper reason why the `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}` works in many situations. I just use it regularly because it seems to work smoothly.